# JQuery: how to get specific attribute type count, of multiple elements starting with same ID characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
....<span id="elem_id0" style="....color:blue...">some text</span>
....<span id="elem_id1" style="....color:blue...">some text</span>
....<span id="elem_id2" style="....color:black...">some different text</span>
....<span id="elem_id3" style="....color:blue...">some text</span>
...
```

I am changing the color dynamically using javascript. at the ned of it all, I want to have a count of all elements whose id began with elem_id" and color is "blue".

I am trying following. (tried many variations). total is coming up right, but blue count is always coming 0. dont know why....

```
var blues = $('#[id^="elem_id"][font-color="blue"]').length;            
var total = $('#[id^="elem_id"]').length;
```

Pl advice.

*****UPDATE****************

removed the previous update. The failure was due to typo in adding attr (added with a white space before color). and hence it failed when matching (no white space here...).

I have fixed my mistake all good now.

thx to all.

Comment: using a class instead of the style attribute will make this much less painful.

Comment: hi Jason, I did try to change it by using classes (add and remove). built class color_blue in css file. the add and remove of class works fine. but the count still shows zero. when i try to count the specific class i built for color blue. $('[id^="elem_id"][class="color_blue"]').length; I get 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var blues = $('[id^="elem_id"][style*="color:blue"]').length;
```

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gpK5G/)**

Comment: thx. I see it is correct and works in fiddle. but in my document it is failing.... It seems this has something to do with binding actions to elements. I have updated my post, pl check. ty.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is no attribute font-color on the element.

```
var blues = $('[id^=elem_id]').filter(
  function() {
     var color = jQuery(this).css("color");
     return color==="rgb(0, 0, 255)" || color==="blue";    
  }
);
console.log(blues.length);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCkyV/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a filter.. See below,

```
$('span[id^=elem_id]').filter(function () {
    return this.style.color == 'blue';
}).length
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/braQw/